# Cannot access nested json key value

Tags: getjson, each

My json structure:
http://snag.gy/da0nf.jpg

my jquery: (  http://jsfiddle.net/EAcs9/2/  )

```
var wotAPI = "http://api.worldoftanks.com/2.0/clan/info/?";
$.getJSON( wotAPI, {application_id: "16924c431c705523aae25b6f638c54dd",clan_id: "1000013300"})

.done( function( jsonData ) {
$.each( jsonData.data, function( i ) { 
        $('#result').append(i);
    });
});
```

I would like to iterate the members in my JSON object and access each member to get their account_name.  I can't seem to get this to work.  Can someone have a look at tell me how to resolve this.  I think I am missing a concept here.

Comment: JavaScript in HTML pane?

Comment: You probably meant to do something closer to: http://jsfiddle.net/EAcs9/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your real issue is in this code.  What is it supposed to do, because I dont think it's doing what you think it's doing.

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }

    return objects;
}
```

Looks like objects is reset to be an empty array on every iteration of the recursion.

Comment: I'm referring to jsfiddle.net/EAcs9/2 I was playing around with the /1/ version of which you've commented on. You were very quick to respond before i managed to correct the url.